# How do I send SKU to the email array?

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to get the SKU on the confirmation E-mail when an order is completed (I have custom PHP code handling SKUs) but only the product IDs are output to `$commerce_order`. I'd like to (need to) work with SKUs. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not do all of this with Rules? you probably have it installed anyways, might as well use it.

Comment: @NoSssweat , about your "probably", check line 6 in [this file](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/commerce.info) ... Get it? BTW: no longer true in D8 ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I guess there is a extremely small chance this is for D8, so I figured I play it safe.

Comment: @NoSssweat : if a question doesn't say which Drupal version it is about, IMO any answer has the right to include an assumption like "I assume this is about Dx (which is also what my answer is about)". At least for as long as there is no official "verdict" about the Featured-on-meta-right-now question. Looking at the votes there for each of the answers, that verdict is obvious I think (= the "*community*" has spoken, right?).

Comment: Hi, thak you, my mistake, it is D7. Rules installed, email works okay, but I'm not able to work with SKU in $commerce_order array, the only thing there is is product ID (for example 89, while SKU is MFA-250-L), because I have custom code, which is outputting XLS file with SKUs, I need SKU :) )